# What items can not be traded with other players?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I tried giving someone a pale tongue recently. I left it on the ground but despire me pointing down vigorously, he didn't seem to see it. I'm not sure if he just ignored it or if it was actually not visible for him. I've also read that you can apparently not trade upgrade materials.

Are there any items that you can leave on the ground, but that can not be seen or picked up by other players? If so, which ones are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Fextralife Wiki | Player Trade](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Player+Trade) entry, you cannot transfer:

- Upgrade materials
- Covenants offerings
- Key items
- Spells
- Boss Souls

Also, there are restrictions on weapon trading - you cannot trade an upgraded weapon to a player until that player has upgraded another weapon to the same level by themselves (i.e. to give +10 weapon to your friend, he must already have some other weapon upgraded to +10).